# Scheduling batch data insertion into Hive using Nifi

Tags: hive, hiveql, apache-nifi

I'm using ***Nifi*** to manage my data flow.
I first receive data using **ConsumeKafka** processor, then **EvaluateJsonPath** and **ReplaceText** processors to obtain this request

```
insert into my_table values('x1','x2','x3');
```

and finally, this request is fed to **PuthiveQl** processor.
In this way, I insert data row by row into my Hive table, working fine but it's a very bad approach.

All what I want to know is how to obtain a request like that

```
insert into my_table values('x1','x2','x3'),('x11','x22','x33'),('x111','x222','x333');
```

by inserting a ; to the query in the end of the day, and so obtain a batch data insert into hive every 24 hours.

Please find attached my data flow in Nifi.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution but only for the first part.
Using this data flow

[image]

I could finally obtain a query like that

> insert into my_table values('x1','x2','x3'),('x11','x22','x33'),('x111','x222','x333');

I used the first ReplaceText processor to get only values to insert with comma in the end
[image]

Then I merged content (maximum and minimum number of entries to set)
The second ReplaceText processor is to add the sentence ***insert into my_table values*** in the beginning of the merged content
[image]

And finally, I used a third ReplaceText processor to replace the last **,** by a **;** at the end of the query.
[image]

For the task of scheduling I've not yet found a solution.